# Unable to scroll down page on Android device

Tags: java, android, selenium, appium

I am unable to scroll down in mobile page on an android device using appium. I have tried driver.scrollTo(element) , it is not scrolling down to the specified element.
I have tried using Actions class but I got an error as "Method has not been implemented yet"
I have tried another approach using Javascript but it didn't work either.
Someone give suggestion.

Here is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();

        cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "Android"); //Name of mobile web browser to automate. Should be an empty string if automating an app instead.
        cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.VERSION, "6.0.1");
        cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.PLATFORM, "Mac");
        cap.setCapability("platformName", "android");
        cap.setCapability("platformVersion", "6.0.1");
        cap.setCapability("deviceName", "4d00a89e4b2631e9");
        cap.setCapability("app", "/Users/ds_nivedha/Downloads/flipkart.apk");
        cap.setCapability("appPackage", "com.usablenet.mobile.walgreen"); //Replace with your app's package
        cap.setCapability("appActivity", "com.usablenet.mobile.walgreen.AppStart"); //Replace with app's Activity
        driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), cap);

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(90, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        /* MobileElement skip= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.RelativeLayout[1]/android.support.v4.view.ViewPager[1]/android.widget.RelativeLayout[1]/android.widget.RelativeLayout[2]/android.widget.Button[1]"));
        skip.click(); */

         MobileElement skiparrow=
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.RelativeLayout[1]/android.support.v4.view.ViewPager[1]/android.widget.RelativeLayout[1]/android.widget.RelativeLayout[3]/android.widget.ImageButton[1]"));
        skiparrow.click(); 

        MobileElement skiparrowRefill=
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.RelativeLayout[1]/android.support.v4.view.ViewPager[1]/android.widget.RelativeLayout[1]/android.widget.RelativeLayout[2]/android.widget.ImageButton[1]"));

        skiparrowRefill.click();

        MobileElement skiparrowPaperless=
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.RelativeLayout[1]/android.support.v4.view.ViewPager[1]/android.widget.RelativeLayout[1]/android.widget.RelativeLayout[2]/android.widget.ImageButton[1]"));

        skiparrowPaperless.click();

        MobileElement done=
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.RelativeLayout[1]/android.support.v4.view.ViewPager[1]/android.widget.RelativeLayout[1]/android.widget.RelativeLayout[1]/android.widget.Button[1]"));
        done.click();



        MobileElement shopProducts=
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.RelativeLayout[1]/android.widget.RelativeLayout[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView[1]/android.widget.RelativeLayout[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout[2]/android.widget.TextView[2]"));
        shopProducts.click();

        MobileElement personalCare=
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.RelativeLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.ScrollView[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.GridView[1]/android.widget.TextView[2]"));
        personalCare.click();


        MobileElement hairCare=
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.RelativeLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.RelativeLayout[1]/android.widget.ListView[1]/android.widget.TextView[3]"));
        hairCare.click();


        MobileElement stylingProduct=
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.RelativeLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.RelativeLayout[1]/android.widget.ListView[1]/android.widget.TextView[3]"));
        stylingProduct.click();

        MobileElement faroukAddToCart=
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.RelativeLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.RelativeLayout[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.webkit.WebView[1]/android.webkit.WebView[1]/android.view.View[1]/android.view.View[1]/android.view.View[1]/android.view.View[1]/android.view.View[3]/android.view.View[2]/android.view.View[1]/android.view.View[3]/android.view.View[1]/android.view.View[1]/android.view.View[4]/android.view.View[1]/android.view.View[1]/android.view.View[2]/android.widget.Button[1]"));
        faroukAddToCart.click();

        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//android.widget.Button[contains(@resource-id,'addToCart-cart-checkout')]")));

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.Button[contains(@resource-id,'addToCart-cart-checkout')]")).click();

        //driver.scrollTo("Proceed to checkout");

        MobileElement proceedToCheckout=
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.Button[contains(@resource-id,'proceedtocheckout')]"));


        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", proceedToCheckout);
        Thread.sleep(500); 

        /* Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
        actions.moveToElement(proceedToCheckout);
        actions.perform(); */

        MobileElement checkout=
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.RelativeLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.RelativeLayout[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.webkit.WebView[1]/android.webkit.WebView[1]/android.view.View[1]/android.view.View[1]/android.view.View[1]/android.view.View[1]/android.view.View[1]/android.view.View[2]/android.view.View[2]/android.view.View[5]/android.view.View[2]/android.view.View[5]/android.view.View[1]/android.view.View[1]/android.view.View[1]/android.view.View[1]/android.view.View[1]/android.widget.Button[1]"));
        checkout.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use swipe method 
Keep start x and end x value constant and change start y and end y  values to scroll up or down

Comment: `Swpie` is deprecated from java client 4.0 version

Comment: scrollTo() and scrollToExact() became deprecated. They are going to be removed in the next release. not swipe  https://discuss.appium.io/t/java-client-4-0-0-released/10434

Comment: You can override swipe(int startx, int starty, int endx, int endy, int duration) to something like:

new TouchAction(getDriver()).press(startx, starty).waitAction(duration).moveTo(endx - startx, endy - starty).release().perform();

Comment: Ohh yes, my bad, scroll is depreciated not swipe

Answer (score 0):

The `scrollTo()` method is deprecated now, you can check on the official site over  [here](http://appium.github.io/java-client/io/appium/java_client/ScrollsTo.html)

Instead if it you can use `swipe` method to swipe vertically on mobile device and to check if your expected text is visible or not, in not then you can make more swipes, of course you will be using loop for doing so.
To know more about `Swipe` refer [here](http://appium.github.io/java-client/io/appium/java_client/AppiumDriver.html#swipe(int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int))

For `Swipe` method refer below example

```
 public void swipingVertical() throws InterruptedException {
  //Get the size of screen.
  size = driver.manage().window().getSize();
  System.out.println(size);

  //Find swipe start and end point from screen's with and height.
  //Find starty point which is at bottom side of screen.
  int starty = (int) (size.height * 0.80);
  //Find endy point which is at top side of screen.
  int endy = (int) (size.height * 0.20);
  //Find horizontal point where you wants to swipe. It is in middle of screen width.
  int startx = size.width / 2;
  System.out.println("starty = " + starty + " ,endy = " + endy + " , startx = " + startx);

  //Swipe from Bottom to Top.
  driver.swipe(startx, starty, startx, endy, 3000);
  Thread.sleep(2000);
  //Swipe from Top to Bottom.
  driver.swipe(startx, endy, startx, starty, 3000);
  Thread.sleep(2000);
 }
```

Let me know if you face any more hurdle in this.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response.   I tried this but I couldn't perform scroll down. I modified your code a bit for scrolling down vertically.                                    Dimension size = driver.manage().window().getSize();
  System.out.println(size);
   int starty = (int) (size.height * 0.80);
   int endy = (int) (size.height * 0.20);
   int startx = size.width / 2;
   System.out.println("starty = " + starty + " ,endy = " + endy + " , startx = " + startx);

   driver.swipe(startx, endy, startx, starty, 3000);
   Thread.sleep(2000);

Comment: Actually it didn't work for me either. I tried different approach.this worked for me.Dimension dimensions = driver.manage().window().getSize();
  Double screenHeightStart = dimensions.getHeight() * 0.5;
  int scrollStart = screenHeightStart.intValue();
  System.out.println("s="+scrollStart);
  Double screenHeightEnd = dimensions.getHeight() * 0.2;
  int scrollEnd = screenHeightEnd.intValue();
  for (int i = 0; i < dimensions.getHeight(); i++) {
  driver.swipe(0,scrollStart,0,scrollEnd,2000);